# Why is my JQuery running slow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am extremely new to JQuery, I just started looking into it today. I have searched all around for what might be causing this bit of code to not work. When you scroll down, I want the h1 to move to the side and a menu button to appear. That works, but when I scroll back up again, it takes an extremely long time to reverse itself. I have tried to fine anything that might be causing it like a delay or something, but as far as I can see, there isn't any problems.
Link to website: http://www.dragonmath.net/rockets

Here is my code:

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css" />
        <title>Rockets</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img id="menu" src="images/menu1.png" />
            <div id="headerdiv">
                <h1>Rockets</h1>
                <img id="logo" src="images/logo1.png" />
            </div>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a>Space Race</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>SpaceX</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                var $menu = $('img#menu');
                var $headerdiv = $("div#headerdiv")
                var $nav = $('nav');


                $(window).on('scroll', function () {
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 40) {
                        $headerdiv.addClass("testheaderdiv");
                        $menu.delay(800).slideDown(800);
                        $nav.addClass('testnav');
                    }
                    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 40) {
                        $menu.slideUp(800, function () {
                            $headerdiv.removeClass('testheaderdiv');
                        });
                        $nav.removeClass('testnav');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: #00AAFF;
    font-family: Arial;
}

body {
    height: 800px;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    z-index: 1;
}

div#headerdiv {
    display: inline;
    transition: all 1s;
}

h1 {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-size: 40px;
}

header > img#menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: none;
}

header > div > img#logo {
    display: inline;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: 18px;
    left: 20px;
    transition: height 1s, width 1s;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
}

nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #00AAFF;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}

.testheaderdiv {
    margin-left: 80px;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.testnav {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem I could see with the code is how scroll is handled, for every scroll event you are adding delay to the `menu` element.

So try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $menu = $('img#menu');
    var $headerdiv = $("div#headerdiv")
    var $nav = $('nav');


    var flag;
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        if (flag !== 1 && $(window).scrollTop() > 40) {
            $headerdiv.addClass("testheaderdiv");
            $menu.stop(true, true).delay(800).slideDown(800);
            $nav.addClass('testnav');
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (flag !== 2 && $(window).scrollTop() < 40) {
            $menu.stop(true, true).slideUp(800, function () {
                $headerdiv.removeClass('testheaderdiv');
            });
            $nav.removeClass('testnav');
            flag = 2;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So it is slow because it is having to do the delay every time it checks the scroll?

Comment: @Taylor yes... so for the animation to work all the delays that was added before need to be executed... so we can use [.stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear any items in the animation queue and use a flag to make sure that each if block is executed only once on the switch over case

Comment: That makes a lot more sense.